# Cannot resize APFS container after updating to Big Sur

Tags: apfs, diskutil, beta, big-sur

I've installed Big Sur beta 2 and tried to use Boot Camp Assistant but I got the error "disk could not be partitioned". Also tried to partition manually but "a problem occurred while resizing APFS container structures". I don't use Time Machine but there were 3 snapshots starting with com.apple.os.update- that can't be deleted. I ran First Aid and fsck_apfs and no problem was found. Any other thing to try? Thanks!

Comment: Note that since Big Sur is a *developer only* beta you **WILL** have problems with it that you are expected to not share with the world at large (read the NDA you signed to be able to download Apple beta software). the best way to handle these is to file an official bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a fix! Deleting snapshots using `tmutil` didn't work but I deleted them with `diskutil` from Recovery:  `diskutil apfs listSnapshots <Macintosh HD's disk id>` and then `diskutil apfs deleteSnapshot <disk id> -uuid <snapshot uuid from the previous command>` for every snapshot. I had 3, two of them were deleted and one returned "insufficient privileges" but it doesn't matter, now everything works. Do it at your own risk, I don't know whether it will work on your Mac.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0 0
```

You could vary the statement if you have a specific size in mind but you also just set it to 0 and it will grow to maximum physical disk size.

You can do this after copying the Time Machine image to a new disk for example.

Comment: You save my day!! This worked to resize a 500gb disk cloned with dd from a 128 SSD. Running `sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0 0`grew my disk to 500GB !! Thanks @markdiener10